# PHP Gives no error and does not fill items into database

Tags: php, html, database

I am trying to get secq (secret question) and seca (secret answer) into the database.

I get no errors when I go through the registration progress, and when I echo the variables it goes through POST fine.

[image]

If you see the image above everything is fine except for the fact that secq and seca are not going into database.

How can I fix it?

Code:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = $secq = $seca = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            $param_seca = trim($_POST["seca"]);
            $param_secq = trim($_POST["secq"]);
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, secq, seca) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $param_username,$param_password,$param_secq,$param_seca);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            $param_secq = $secq;
            $param_seca = $seca;
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta property=og:url content="https://treasurebits.net/" />
<meta property=og:type content=website />
<meta property=og:title content=TreasureBits />
<meta property=og:description content="Welcome to TreasureBits.net! This website offers various cryptocurrency faucets and strategies to its users to earn free cryptocurrencies. The users can vary from beginners to pros and will help you maximize your micro earnings!" />
<meta property=og:image content="https://treasurebits.net/images/treasure.png" />
<meta name=description content="Welcome to TreasureBits.net! This website offers various cryptocurrency faucets and strategies to its users to earn free cryptocurrencies. The users can vary from beginners to pros and will help you maximize your micro earnings!">
<script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/C3ZYTVLv_F3wN8HVuyz6VVxx6mU.js"></script><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://treasurebits.net/images/bitcoinlogo.png" />
<title>TreasureBits</title>

<script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">(function (a, b, c) {Object.defineProperty(a, b, {value: c});})(window, 'absda', function () {var _0xf75e=['span','setAttribute','height: inherit; position: relative;','color: white; cursor: pointer; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; position: absolute; right: 30px; top: 20px;','innerHTML','ADBLOCK DETECTED<br/>Unfortunately AdBlock might cause a bad affect on displaying content of this website. Please, deactivate it.','&#10006;','click','parentNode','removeChild','addEventListener','createElement','div','&nbsp;','className','style','position','absolute','left','-99999px','body','appendChild','offsetHeight'];(function(_0x1b51b2,_0x292bdf){var _0x266de7=function(_0x4a062c){while(--_0x4a062c){_0x1b51b2['push'](_0x1b51b2['shift']());}};_0x266de7(++_0x292bdf);}(_0xf75e,0xc2));var _0x4e13=function(_0x31e2a4,_0x4eccd5){_0x31e2a4=_0x31e2a4-0x0;var _0x2f1ef2=_0xf75e[_0x31e2a4];return _0x2f1ef2;};window[_0x4e13('0x0')]('DOMContentLoaded',function(){var _0x1b0f57=document[_0x4e13('0x1')](_0x4e13('0x2'));_0x1b0f57['innerHTML']=_0x4e13('0x3'),_0x1b0f57[_0x4e13('0x4')]='adsBox',_0x1b0f57[_0x4e13('0x5')][_0x4e13('0x6')]=_0x4e13('0x7'),_0x1b0f57[_0x4e13('0x5')][_0x4e13('0x8')]=_0x4e13('0x9'),document[_0x4e13('0xa')][_0x4e13('0xb')](_0x1b0f57),setTimeout(function(){if(0x0===_0x1b0f57[_0x4e13('0xc')]){var _0x2adb51=document[_0x4e13('0x1')](_0x4e13('0x2')),_0x5d5bc3=document[_0x4e13('0x1')](_0x4e13('0x2')),_0x554d62=document[_0x4e13('0x1')](_0x4e13('0xd')),_0x24dd7d=document[_0x4e13('0x1')]('p');_0x2adb51[_0x4e13('0xe')](_0x4e13('0x5'),'background-color: black; height: 100%; left: 0; opacity: .7; top: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 2147483650;'),_0x5d5bc3[_0x4e13('0xe')](_0x4e13('0x5'),_0x4e13('0xf')),_0x554d62[_0x4e13('0xe')](_0x4e13('0x5'),_0x4e13('0x10')),_0x24dd7d[_0x4e13('0xe')](_0x4e13('0x5'),'color: white; font-size: 35px; font-weight: bold; left: 0; line-height: 1.5; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; text-align: center; top: 150px; position: absolute; right: 0;'),_0x24dd7d[_0x4e13('0x11')]=_0x4e13('0x12'),_0x554d62[_0x4e13('0x11')]=_0x4e13('0x13'),_0x5d5bc3['appendChild'](_0x24dd7d),_0x5d5bc3[_0x4e13('0xb')](_0x554d62),_0x554d62[_0x4e13('0x0')](_0x4e13('0x14'),function(){_0x2adb51[_0x4e13('0x15')][_0x4e13('0x16')](_0x2adb51);}),_0x2adb51[_0x4e13('0xb')](_0x5d5bc3),document[_0x4e13('0xa')][_0x4e13('0xb')](_0x2adb51);}},0xc8);});});</script><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript" onerror="absda()" src='//4bb6jls06l.com/78/80/3a/78803a0cc569feed08a77531ad75b00b.js'></script>

<meta name="maValidation" content="cf9394b6bba261d9134e60717a751c5b" />
</head>
<body width="width: 50%;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<style>
        .w3-sidebar a, .dropdown-btn {
            padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #818181;
            display: block;
            border: none;
            background: none;
            width:100%;
            text-align: left;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
        }
        .w3-sidebar a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
            color: #f1f1f1;
            border: none;
        }
        .active {
            background-color: #A9A9A9;
            color: white;
            border: none;
        }
        .dropdown-container {
            display: none;
            border: none;
            background-color: #262626;
            padding-left: 50px;
        }
        .fa-caret-down {
            float: right;
            padding-right: 1px;
            border: none;
        }
        hr { 
            display: block;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            border-style: inset;
            border-width: 1px;
            color: #262626;
        }
        figure {
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
        }
        figure1 {
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
        }
        .icon-bar a {
            float: left;
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0px 15px;
            font-size: 26px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #818181;
            border: none;
            background: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .icon-bar a:hover {
            color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
             width: 10px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #696969; 
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: #696969; 
        }
        @keyframes shake {
            0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
            10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
            20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
            30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
            40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
            50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
            60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
            70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
            80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
            90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
        }
    </style>
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card w3-animate-left" style="min-width: 245px; background-color: #111; color: #818181;" id="mySidebar">
<a href="https://treasurebits.net/"><img width="160px" height="35px" style="margin-left: 10px" src="https://treasurebits.net/images/logot.png"></a>
<a href="https://treasurebits.net/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-white" style="padding: 10px 10px 14px 10px;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
<a href="https://treasurebits.net/pages/earnmore/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-white" style="padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-money"></i> Earn More</a>
<a href="https://treasurebits.net/miner/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-white" style="padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cloud"></i> TreasureBits Miner</a>
<button class="dropdown-btn">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-bitcoin"></i> TreasureBits Faucets<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
<a href="https://bitcoin.treasurebits.net/">Bitcoin</a>
<a href="https://bitcoincash.treasurebits.net/">BitcoinCash</a>
<a href="https://dash.treasurebits.net/">Dash</a>
<a href="https://dogecoin.treasurebits.net/">Dogecoin</a>
<a href="https://ethereum.treasurebits.net/">Ethereum</a>
<a href="https://litecoin.treasurebits.net/">Litecoin</a>
<a href="https://monero.treasurebits.net/">Monero</a>
</div>
<button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gamepad"></i> Games
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
<a href="https://cointiply.com/r/BpQ5x" target=_blank rel=nofollow>Cointiply</a>
<a href="https://tracker-pm2.fortunejackpartners.com/link?btag=1732323_55124" target=_blank rel=nofollow>Fortune Jack</a>
<a href="https://starcoins.ws/r/14705" target=_blank rel=nofollow>StarCoins</a>
</div>
<button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exchange"></i> Trade/Exchange
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
<a href="https://www.coinbase.com/join/596ae2b6e06d7b0098538adc" target=_blank rel=nofollow>Coinbase</a>
<a href="https://www.kucoin.com/#/?r=7r2udJ" target=_blank rel=nofollow>Kucoin</a>
</div>

<button class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i> Advertisers
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
<a href="//ad.a-ads.com/903799?size=468x60" target=_blank rel=nofollow>A-ads</a>
<a href="https://publishers.adsterra.com/referral/ZAdr1D85Qp" target=_blank rel=nofollow>Adsterra</a>
<a href="https://www.bitcoadz.io/?rid=25044" target=_blank rel=nofollow>Bicoadz</a>
</div>
<a href="login.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-white" style="padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;"><i class=""></i> Login</a>
<a href="register.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-white" style="padding: 14px 10px 14px 10px;"><i class=""></i> Register</a>
<hr>
<center>
<figure1><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TreasureBitcoins/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook-official" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
<figure1><a href="https://twitter.com/TreasuresBit" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter-square" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
<figure1><a href="https://t.me/treasurebits" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-telegram" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
<figure1><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#84f7f1f4f4ebf6f0c4f0f6e1e5f7f1f6e1e6edf0f7aaeae1f0" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
</center>
<center>
<figure1><a href="https://discord.gg/Vc3YK5t" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
<figure1><a href="https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5024159.0" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bitcoin" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
<figure1><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoFaucets/comments/9e0gdk/treasurebits_multicryptocurrency_faucet_mining/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-reddit" style="font-size:26px"></i></a></figure1>
</center>
<hr>
<center><script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script id="cid0020000194930595478" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 245px;height: 340px;">{"handle":"treasurebitschat","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"383838","b":100,"c":"ffffff","d":"ffffff","e":"ffffff","h":"ffffff","k":"383838","l":"383838","m":"383838","n":"ffffff","p":"9","q":"383838","r":100,"ab":false,"usricon":0,"bpos":"bl","cv":1,"cvfntsz":"12px","cvfg":"ffffff","cvw":150,"cvh":30,"sbc":"bbbbbb","surl":0,"cnrs":"1"}}</script></center>
</div>
<script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">
            function w3_open() {
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "245px";
                document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "245px";
                document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("openNav1").style.display = "inline-block";
                document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("openNav").style.border = "none";
            }
            function w3_close() {
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
                document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("openNav1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
                document.getElementById("openNav").style.border = "none";
            }
    </script>
<script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">
        var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
            dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
                    dropdownContent.style.border = "none";
                } else {
                    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
                    dropdownContent.style.border = "none";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<div id="main" style="margin-left: 245px; ">
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-cell w3-cell-top" style="border:10px solid grey; width:13%; min-width: 169px;">
<hr>
<center><button id="openNav1" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-grey" style="display:none; color: black; border: none; outline:none;" onclick="w3_close()">&#9776; MENU</button></center>
<center><button id="openNav" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-none w3-hover-text-grey" style=" color: black; border: none; outline:none;" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776; MENU</button></center>
<hr>
<center><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript" src="https://adhitzads.com/1002996"></script></center>
<center><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">
                atOptions = {
                    'key' : 'b9e5ea99e13bfe0ff36c672c42ab3b38',
                    'format' : 'iframe',
                    'height' : 600,
                    'width' : 160,
                    'params' : {}
                };
                document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bcloudhost.com/b9e5ea99e13bfe0ff36c672c42ab3b38/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
            </script></center>
<center><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">
                atOptions = {
                    'key' : '51e5be8e82e68689982d4a237c5cd5c4',
                    'format' : 'iframe',
                    'height' : 300,
                    'width' : 160,
                    'params' : {}
                };
                document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bcloudhost.com/51e5be8e82e68689982d4a237c5cd5c4/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
            </script></center>
<center><iframe data-aa="979482" src="//ad.a-ads.com/979482?size=160x600" scrolling="no" style="width:160px; height:600px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></center>
<p></p>
</div>
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-cell w3-cell-top" style="border-top:10px solid grey; border-bottom:10px solid grey; width:58%; min-width: 465px;  font-size:16px;  padding-right:0; padding-left:0;">
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-cell w3-cell-top" style="border-bottom:10px solid grey;">
 <center><h1><b>Register!</b></h1></center>
<hr>
<center>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2></h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Secret Question</label>
                <input type="" name="secq" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $secq; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Secret Question Answer</label>
                <input type="" name="seca" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $seca; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form></center>
<p></p>
<hr>
<center><script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">
                    atOptions = {
                        'key' : '7db004f79c21c29292a5221a197384a0',
                        'format' : 'iframe',
                        'height' : 90,
                        'width' : 728,
                        'params' : {}
                    };
                    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bcloudhost.com/7db004f79c21c29292a5221a197384a0/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
                </script></center>
<center><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript" src="https://adhitzads.com/1002994"></script></center>
<center><div id="data_23164"></div><script data-cfasync="false" async type="text/javascript" src="//www.bitcoadz.io/display/items.php?23164&25044&728&90&4&0&0&0"></script></center>
<center><iframe data-aa='979609' src='//ad.a-ads.com/979609?size=728x90' scrolling='no' style='width:728px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true'></iframe></center>
<hr>


</center></b>
<hr>
<br>

</div>
</div>
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-cell w3-cell-top" style="border-top:10px solid grey; border-right:10px solid grey; border-left:10px solid grey; border-bottom:10px solid grey; width:13%; min-width: 169px; ">
<p></p>
<center><script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript" src="https://adhitzads.com/1003000"></script></center>
<p></p>
<center><iframe data-aa="984505" src="//ad.a-ads.com/984505?size=120x90" scrolling="no" style="width:120px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></center>
<center><iframe data-aa="984017" src="//ad.a-ads.com/984017?size=120x240" scrolling="no" style="width:120px; height:240px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></center>
<p></p>
<center><div id="data_22511"></div><script data-cfasync="false" async type="text/javascript" src="//www.bitcoadz.io/display/items.php?22511&25044&160&600&4&0&0&0"></script></center>
<p></p>
<center><div id="data_22716"></div><script data-cfasync="false" async type="text/javascript" src="//www.bitcoadz.io/display/items.php?22716&25044&160&600&4&0&0&0"></script></center>
<p></p> </div>
<div id=data_15258></div><script data-cfasync=false async src="//www.bitcoadz.io/display/items.php?15258&25044&0&0&9"></script>
<script src="https://pkg.moonify.io/moonify.min.js" type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript"></script>
<script type="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-text/javascript">
            Moonify.set({serviceID:"vVW7FHeSkp9LGk1ll7QB7rdyZSOu225qzSN0Siz-hOdeEn-hefFCWN35fVLK7JdeTypDIJq1N5jKE5mUDVZNnoOsyvFvUeE3s0WFvgQAzbs4Juzr5XsTLJvDSn8uwa35"});
            //... Do some stuff ...
            Moonify.start();
        </script>
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/2448a7bd/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" data-cf-nonce="2215151d9caf119f7aa679d7-" defer=""></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. While this is no answer to this question, I still recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication/477578#477578) post about using security questions. (Especially part three)

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Comment: `$param_secq = trim($_POST["secq"]);` looks wrong to me; I think it should be `$secq = trim($_POST["secq"]);`; and the same for `seca`.

Comment: @jh1711 I will test it out

Comment: @jh1711 IT WORKS! YOU ARE A GENIUS, THANK YOU!

Comment: @mahanaad, Great. For future question, please try to reduce the size of the code. It makes it much easier to spot potential issues.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, I see that you define:

```
$param_seca = trim($_POST["seca"]);
```

But It is replaced by an empty value `$secq` and `$seca`, defined in the start code:

```
$username = $password = $confirm_password = $secq = $seca = "";
```

Just delete these two lines and try again:

```
$param_secq = $secq;
$param_seca = $seca;
```

`$secq` and `$seca` could not to be necessaries, Let me know if it fixes your code.